# Why a loadash flatten() is giving me back an empty object when isnide the function it slef the values are present

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm building a flatten functionality using flatten() from Loadash.
This is required to have an array of objects containing messages which need to be sent it out. Email templates are to be passed to another service which will be sent out to users the email.

The issue is with the following code

```
const messages = flatten(
      input.map(async (recipientObject) => {
        // Validate input
        const { documentId, studyId, recipientDetails } = recipientObject;
        if (isEmpty(studyId) || !documentId || !recipientDetails) {
          log.error('Missing required input variables!');
          return null;
        }

        const { id: recipientId, email, phone, locale } = recipientDetails;
        if (isEmpty(email) && isEmpty(phone)) {
          log.error(
            `Email|Phone for recipient ${recipientId} not found. Invitation can not be sent!`,
            {
              recipientId,
              documentId,
            }
          );
          return null;
        }

        const studyName = await getStudyName(studyId);

        // Prepare the messages to be sent for each recipient and append them to messages array
        const msgs = [];
        const title = `Get started on your eConsent for ${studyName}!`;
        // TODO: change to new message recipientType
        const recipientType = 'EXTERNAL_USER';
        const originType = 'INVITATION';

        if (email) {
          const messageContent = getMessageLinkContent({
            link: tokenLinks[recipientId].link,
            locale,
            type: 'EMAIL',
          });
          msgs.push({
            type: 'EMAIL',
            recipient: email,
            title,
            content: messageContent,
            recipientType,
            originType,
            originId: tokenLinks[recipientId].tokenId,
            extra: {
              template: getContentTemplate({
                templateName: 'invitation',
                locale,
                title,
                messageContent,
                log,
              }),
            },
          });
        }

        if (!msgs || msgs.length < 1) {
          log.error(
            `No messages found for recipient: ${recipientId} on document: ${documentId}!`
          );
          return null;
        }

        log.info(
          `${msgs.length} invitation messages prepared for recipient: ${recipientId} on document: ${documentId} and ready to be added to message-service`
        );
        log.info('INSIDE MESSAGES ---------------------');
        log.info('MESGS %o', msgs); // Messages are present here!!!!
        log.info('RETURN ---------------------');

        return msgs;
      }),
      true
    );
```

In the above snippet when I do a console log of msgs I see my messages and expect that will be also the result of the `const messages`

Instead when I'm doing a console of messages return this `[{}]` an empty obj.

I have no clue what's wrong with that messages.

Cannot spot an issue in my snippet which will allow me to understand why I have inside the messages are present but they are not returned.

Comment: The OP needs to boil down the example code to just the most necessary minimum (e.g omit properties which are of no interest for debugging/solving the problem). Also, providing some test data (lowest possible footprint too) would be appreciated. Another Q. ... has the OP already tried using some commonly used debug environments?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question as I resolved the issue by doing as follow

```
const messages = await Promise.all(<everything_else>);

flatten(messages) // where I need it to use
```

This was empty as I had promises inside and using Promise.all fixed the issue in the end